# Fast Occlusion Discovery between objects in 3D data

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, geometry, raytracing, octree

lets assume a voxelized region (represented by Octree) where occupied voxels are objects. The number of these objects varies in a wide 3D region. Let's say the region is `200(w)` by `200(l)` by `10(h)` and voxel resolution is `0.1`. My algorithm needs to efficiently discover whether the direct path between a given point `P(x,y,z)` and every occupied voxel (object) is occluded by other occupied voxels.

**Possible approach:** Visiting every occupied voxel and trace a ray between point `P` and occupied voxel centroid. Step on each ray with step size of voxel resolution to test if the visiting step is occupied (if it is, then that would be an obstacle).

This ray tracing approach is complex and depends on number of occupied voxels and step size. **Can anyone think of a better algorithm ?**